# convert numeric column to dates recognized by R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, date-conversion

How could I convert this numeric vector of dates into the date format that R can recognize?

```
date <- c(29101958L, 10121957L, 27091953L, 23021960L, 
           6031967L, 10011968L, 10101958L, 9101992)
```

I would like an output like:

```
'1958-10-29', '1957-12-10', '1953-09-27', '1960-02-23', '1967-03-06', '1968-01-10', '1958-10-10', '1992-10-09'
```

Then I would like to calculate the age by making the difference from 2016-12-31 with the dates of the vector.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I gave more information in the question !

Comment: I wonder if the issue is how you read it in in the first place. If you had a number `1111958L`, is it `1958-01-11` or `1958-11-01`? While `dmy` is going to be close, there is certainly room for ambiguity here. Perhaps the issue is better resolved at the point of acquiring the data. (For instance, if using one of `read.*`, then one might use `colClasses=` to force this column to be `character` instead of `integer`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
newdate <- dmy(date)

newdate
#[1] "1958-10-29" "1957-12-10" "1953-09-27" "1960-02-23" "1967-03-06" "1968-01-10" "1958-10-10" "1992-10-09"
```

and get the difference between the new date in years

```
as.integer(difftime(as.Date('2016-12-31'), newdate, units = 'days')/365)
#[1] 58 59 63 56 49 49 58 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `as.Date` :

```
as.Date(sprintf('%08d', date), '%d%m%Y')

#[1] "1958-10-29" "1957-12-10" "1953-09-27" "1960-02-23" "1967-03-06"
#[6] "1968-01-10" "1958-10-10" "1992-10-09"
```

Using `sprintf` we add leading zeroes for single digit dates.